# centering text with python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I need to center a small head of text that is embedded in a table.

traditionally you would center text using the following code

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

paragraph = document.add_paragraph("text here")
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
```

however because I also need to change font and size I need to add that text to an `add_run()` function. and that means that the above code no longer works, it doesn't even give an error it just dose nothing.

my current code is

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
...
paragraph = row.cells[idx].add_paragraph().add_run("text here")
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER    #this line dose not work
```

Another thing that is restricting me from getting the result needed is the fact that `paragraph = document.add_paragraph()` will actually add a line to the table which will throw off the dimentions of the table meaning the following code will not be satisfactory:

```
paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
paragraph.add_run("text here")
```

I would need it to be done in one line as to avoid an extra line being added to the table.

So in summery how do I center a line of text that has been embedded in an `add_run()` function in the same line with `python docx?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited to demo centering text in tables

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

document = Document('demo.docx')

for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for para in cell.paragraphs:
                para.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
                para.add_run("text here")

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Comment: Ahh sorry I forgot to mention that because this is in a table the line ```paragraph = document.add_paragraph()``` will actually add a line, and throw off the dimensions of the table which is why I tried to do it in one line... Otherwise this dose work but not in my case.

Comment: Edited. You were trying to center the return value of add_run(...) instead of setting the alignment of the paragraph containing your text.

Comment: I hate to keep shooting this down but this dose prevent the extra line from being added however now it dosent let me add font attributes the line ```font = para.font``` will now return an error AttributeError: 'para' object has no attribute 'font'

Comment: okay so i did manage to fix this problem by storing the run in another variable like so ```paragraph = para.add_run("text")``` and then I was able to add font attributes with ```font = paragraph.add_font```., cant thank you enough for the help.